# Read .txt file from google cloud storage

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, rdd

I am new to google cloud platform and Spark. I am trying to read a .txt file from google cloud storage. But after downloading it as blob object I am not able to iterate over it. My requirement is to read the file as a simple txt file line by line. Please see the below code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from google.cloud import storage
import sys
conf=SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Popular Movies")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)

bucket_name = (sys.argv[1])
destination_blob_name = (sys.argv[2])

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name)
 
downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
print(downloaded_blob)


print(blob)
def loadMovieNames():
    movies={}
    for line in blob:
        fields=line.split("|")
        print(fields)
        movies[int(fields[0])]=fields[1]
    return movies

myMovies=loadMovieNames()
myRDD=sc.parallelize([myMovies])

print(myRDD.collect())
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you already convert the blob to a string, you can just apply a `splitlines()` to that string to go over it line by line.

```py
def loadMovieNames():
    movies = {}
    for line in downloaded_blob.splitlines():
        fields = line.split("|")
        print(fields)
        movies[int(fields[0])] = fields[1]
    return movies
```

What this does is it splits the single string into a list, splitting at the newline character.

Also, for your next question, please provide exactly what happens with your current code. Providing source data (eg. the sanitized contents of the file you're downloading from GCS) also helps immensely as the community doesn't have to guess.

Remember, the better the question, the better the answer...

Comment: Simpler still, use `.splitlines()`

Comment: I keep forgetting about `splitlines()` . Answer updated accordingly...